# Help identify this vertabrae found on Costa Rica beach

Tags: species-identification, bone

[image: photos of vertebrae]
I was walking down tamarindo beach in Costa Rica today and came upon a really LARGE section of vertabrae.. I matched it against a crocodile a shark , whales, a horse, a cow, a snake even ... any ideas ? It naturally doesn't have another piece beyond the two transgressors bones ... I'm stumped... joined just to ask this... and also I think I found footprints in lava immortalized..  in the same area yesterday... thats a diff post tho w video .. I found the footprints in lava yest.. and went back today to see if I could find them again.. I didnt.. but found this instead... Note : I found another vertabrae about 1/5 its size about 15 ft away .. not sure if same animal

Any guesses?
[image]

Comment: Looks the same on the other side.. trying to upload more pics

Comment: It looks like a tuna/ sea bass / barracuda. may be worn away so we don't have all of the spine.